# Using Express and Spring boot dual backend for Single react Project

Tags: reactjs, spring-boot, express

I have a react frontend project and I am using mongo DB as my database. I want to implement rest api with both spring boot and express JS. It means some of the api calls should done by spring boot and others should done by express js. Is there any option to do this?

Answer (score 1):

I don't see why not. You will have two separate servers running - one NodeJS + ExpressJS, and the other would be Spring Boot. Your client does not need to know what the implementation of these servers are (i.e. Spring Boot, ExpressJS, Java, Python, whatever). The client will just need the URL of the endpoint that is being served by your servers.

This is the beauty of REST - de-coupled client and server.